# Show that a group of order $1755=3^3\times 5\times 13$ must have a normal Sylow $13$ subgroup or a normal Sylow $5$ subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Question: Show that a group of order $1755=3^3\times 5\times 13$ must have a normal Sylow $13$ subgroup or a normal Sylow $5$ subgroup.

My thoughts: $n_{13}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ and $n_{13}\mid  135$, so $n_{13}=1$ or $27$.  If $n_{13}=1$, then we have a normal Sylow $13$ subgroup of $G$, and we're done.  If $n_{13}=27$, then let $Q\in{\rm Syl}_{13}(G)$.  As $G$ acts on $Q$ by conjugation, we induce a homomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow S_{27}$, where $|G:N_G(Q)|=27$, thus $|N_G(Q)|=5\times 13$.  Since $13\neq 1\pmod{5}$, we have that $N_G(Q)$ is cyclic thus abelian.  Let $R\in{\rm Syl}_5(N_G(Q))$, thus $R\trianglelefteq N_G(Q)$.  From here, I am not quite sure how to show that $R$ must then be normal in $G$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Note that the @yoyo answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31420/questions-about-simple-groups 

almost answers this question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof. First, as you noticed, $n_{13}=27$ so there are $12\cdot 27=324$ elements of order $13$ in $G$. Next $n_5$ divides $351$ and $n_5\equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, hence $n_5=351$. Then the number of elements of order $5$ is $351\cdot 4=1404$. The number of elements of order $5$ or $13$ is then $1728$.

There are then at most $1755-1728=27$ elements whose orders are powers of $3$, including $1$. Hence $n_3=1$ and the group $G$ has one normal Sylow 3-subgroup $N$. For every $5$-Sylow subgroup $S$, $SN/N$ is a $5$-Sylow subgroup of $G/N$. If $S'\ne S$ is another Sylow $5$-subgroup, then $SN/N\ne S'N/N$. So $G/N$ has $1404$ elements of order $5$, a contradiction because $|G/N|<1404$.

Comment: $S\neq S'$ does not automatically imply that $SN\neq S'N$. However, in the present case it does, because $SN$ has order $135$ and hence only a single Sylow $5$-subgroup.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: There  are several other gaps in the answer which can be filled  as well. For example, $SN/N$ is not necessarily a Sylow subgroup of $G/N$ but in this case it is.

Comment: Understood. Filling any such "gap" is pretty straight forward :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: The OP has to do some work, hence I always leave gaps in my answers.

Comment: Couldn't we derive an earlier contradiction right after showing $SN/N \neq S'N /N$? Because then we would have shown that $G/N$ has more than one Sylow-5 subgroup, i.e. $n_5(G/N) > 1$ and yet Sylow's Third forces $n_5(G/N) = 1$ (since $|G/N| = 5 \cdot 13$). I'm not following how $G/N$ has $1404$ elements of order $5$.